# binding to a suspended function in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, kotlin-coroutines

I want to bind a button click to a suspended function inside viewmodel.

this is my code:

**RegistrationActivityViewModel.kt**

```
    suspend fun register() {
        if (validateFields()) {
            val result = SourceplusplusApiService.invoke().registerUser(username.value!!, email.value!!, password.value!!).await()
            isRegistrationCompleted.value = getResultValue(result)
        }
    }
```

**activity_registration.xml**

```
<Button
          android:text="Register"
          android:onClick="@{()->viewmodel.register()}"
          android:textSize="16sp" />
```

i get a databinding error that says `ActivityRegistrationBindingImpl` not generated. after searching a lot i realized that when i remove the `suspend` keyword and comment the code inside, it works fine but it has to be a suspended function.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot data bind to a `suspend` function, and IMHO a viewmodel should not be exposing a `suspend` function in the first place. I recommend:

Step #1: Remove the `suspend` keyword from `register()`

Step #2: Rewrite `register()` to run your code in a suitable coroutine scope, so any `suspend` functions that it calls are handled properly:

```
fun register() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        if (validateFields()) {
            val result = SourceplusplusApiService.invoke().registerUser(username.value!!, email.value!!, password.value!!).await()
            isRegistrationCompleted.value = getResultValue(result)
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I am using the `viewModelScope` option provided by `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx` version `2.1.0-alpha01` and newer. Alternatively, manage your own coroutine scope. `Dispatchers.Main` will ensure that any results of that work is available to you on the Android main application thread.

Now, your data binding expression can refer to `register()`, while you still have a coroutine scope for calling downstream `suspend` functions.

Comment: Isn't `Main` already the default dispatcher of `viewModelScope`?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Probably, but I prefer to spell it out in educational materials like this.